# Access instance variables of activity from a thread started by a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handler

Start a thread in a service and try to update the UI in the thread by using handler. Can I just define a handler in the child thread using getMainLooper?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    ... 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                it=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Myservice.class);
                startService(it);
            }

        });
    }

    Handler mhandler= new Handler(){         
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            switch(msg.what){
            case 1:
                edt.setText("Service");
                break;
            }
        }   
    };  

}
```

Myservice.java:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Handler handler=new Handler(getMainLooper());
                Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, 1);
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the UI elements from a (non-UI/main thread) access them from the Handler defined in your main activity.

From the (non-UI/main thread) just keep posting events to the handler to make UI updates.

```
//Inside the Thread's run method
public void run() {
    if(uiNeedsToBeUpdated) {
        handler.sendMessage(updateData);
    }
}
```

---

In your MainActivity code (assuming you've a handler defined as a class member in your main activity), in the handler's `handleMessage()`, update the UI based on the progress made in the background task.

```
public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
    switch(msg.getData().getInt("update")) {
        //assuming you've bundled up int from the sending end 
        case 0 : { // background processing started, update UI
            editText.setText("started");
            break; 
        }
        case 1 : { // background processing  in progress, update UI
            editText.setText("In progress");
            break; 
        }
        case 2:  {  //background processing finished , update UI
            editText.setText("Done");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use an Asyntask instead of a handler (http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/). Using an asynctask is easier as compared to a handler as it makes the programmer's life a little bit easier comparatively. Hope this info helps.

Comment: That's what I did at first. But the handler defined in main activity did not react. Does this work for you? I kind of think the handler defined in main activity and the handler you get using getMainLooper in the service are two different handlers that are bound to the same looper(main looper). So we have two handler instances. I don't know whether this is ture.

Comment: Ideally the hadnler defined in your main activity should have reacted.How did you pass in your handler instance to the Thread instance?can you share the code please.

Comment: Also try dispatchMessage() instead of sendMessage(), sometimes this works.

Comment: I have attached my code of handler defined in the mainactivity. Thank you.

Comment: in fact it would be easier if you can share the entire code. Thanks

Comment: The  Handler handler=new Handler(getMainLooper()); in the Service code is a different handler than the Activity handler( Handler mhandler= new Handler()). How about passing the handler from the Activity to the service.See my new Answer.

Comment: But how do you start a service? still using intent? How can you make sure the service you start later is the same instance of the service you new in your activity. And also is that ok for an acitivity to hold an instance of service? Sorry about this but I just have too many questions.

Comment: The process of starting a service (using intents) would remain unaffected. As for calling a start on an already started service, Android takes care of it, it doesn't invoke the onCreate() lifecycle method hence making sure that a new instance is not created for a started service. The activity doesn't need to hold an instance of the service, whatever it needs it picks up from the handler or any user defined interface which acts as a medium between the foreground activity and the background service.

Comment: But you new a service in the activity, so you hold an instance of service in the activity. right?

Comment: It's a local variable not a class field. MyService myService =  new MyService(mHandler); This is just a local variable, not a class field.

Comment: myService is not declared in a method. How come it is a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

The Handler handler=new Handler(getMainLooper()); in the Service code is probably a different handler instance than the Activity handler( Handler mhandler= new Handler()). How about passing the handler from the Activity to the service.See my new Answer.
for e.g. Suppose there's a class called MYService :

```
 public Myservice extends Service  {

   private Handler acitivityHandler;

   public MyService(Handler handler) {

      this.activityHandler =  handler;

   }

 }
```

---

And from your activity when invoking the service pass-in the activity's handler instance 
instead of relying on the main looper.

```
 Handler mhandler= new Handler(){         
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        switch(msg.what){
        case 1:
            edt.setText("Service");
            break;
        }
    }   
};  
MyService myService  =  new MyService(mhandler);
```

That should work ideally.